# Java - what is the fastest method to replace string from array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have array of three elements of strings, 0,1,2. And I have string

```
this is $0 string some text here $1 another text here $2 and some here
```

what is the fastest method to replace $0 to array[0], $1 to array[1] and $2 to array[2]. I need the fastest because I have really a lot of operations like this.

**EDIT:**

Currently I use the following method:

```
Formatter formatter=new Formatter();
String[] array=new String[]{"aaa","bbb","ccc"};
String result=formatter.format("some text %s another tett %s more text %s",array));
```

Comment: Half the people asking basic questions like this "need the fastest" or "the most efficient" way. How are you doing it currently? Also how many is "really a lot of operations"?

Comment: hardware is so rubbish these days that they need to eek out the very last cpu cycle.

Comment: @Kayaman See my edit

Comment: @JimJim2000 And how many operations do you expect to be performing?

Comment: @Kayaman about 12 500 000

Comment: @JimJim2000 Have you profiled the code and identified the formatting to be a bottleneck?

Comment: Have you timed this? Doing the replace in another way is not going to give you a 50% performance increase afaik. You could look at multiple threads or something.

Comment: I did a test run with `Formatter` and it did 12,5M in ~16 seconds (on a beefy laptop). Doesn't seem like too bad performance per se. But still waiting for the profiling results from Jim.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `StringBuffer` and assuming that your markers are "sorted" (i.e. $0,$1,$2, and not more than 10 markers, you can use

```
    String[] array = new String[]{"0", "1", "2"};
    String orig = "this is $0 string some text here $1 another text here $2 and some here";

    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer(orig);
    int lastIndex = -2;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int i1 = orig.indexOf("$",lastIndex+2);
        b.replace(i1, i1 + 2, array[i]);
        lastIndex = i1;
    }
    String s = b.toString();
```

Using JHM, it seems this is about 2-3 times faster than

```
 String.format(orig, array)
```

but is obviously not as generally applicable. And who knows, maybe (or quite probably, actually) there is a bug in my code.